# How can I add programmatically welcome message with user name

Tags: magento-1.9, global-messages

How can I add programmetically  welcome message with user name, with this welcome message display all of my page.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome message displayed using `page/html_welcome` block. Welcome message that is displayed before user login and after user login directly created in `_toHtml` function in `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Welcome` Block class.

You can rewrite this block to add your customize message. Also you can create your own module block function that have customize code and make a new block in layout as below:

```
<block type="custom/module_welcome" name="welcome_custom" as="welcome_custom" />
```

Comment: my template differ from other, could you pls briefly explain.